# WPF Expander header with buttons that should always be enabled

Tags: wpf, expander

I would like to have an expander that is disabled when there is no content to display in the expanded content area, but at the same time I would like to have buttons in the header that are always enabled.

The below XAML doesnt work as the expander is disabled, then the button is disabled as well. So it seems that something (default style) is overriding my IsEnabled setting for the button.

```
<Expander
   IsEnabled="False"
   IsExpanded="False">
   <Expander.Header>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <TextBlock>Short header text</TextBlock>
       <Button Content="Always enabled" IsEnabled="True" />
     </StackPanel>
  </Expander.Header>
  <TextBlock Text="Not to be seen by the user, as the expander should be disabled to expand" />
</Expander>
```

Result:[image: Outcome]

Wanted result: [image]

Somehow it seems that the IsEnabled is always set to False on the stackpanel, textblock and button in the header. I have tried using a  with  that sucessfully changes the background of the header (to red) but the button is still not enabled.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StretchableExpanderHeader">
  <Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" x:Name="ContentPresenter"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger SourceName="Grid" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
      <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there any way to enable the button without re-styling the expander completly? Preferably I would like anyone to be able to style it as they want but the buttons should not be affected in the header.

Comment: You can use MVVM, and bind the IsEnabled property to the Model. It seems difficult, but it will make easier later.

Comment: re: Tony, My code is using MVVM, the above code is just an example of what the model will yield to the view in order to keep it simple. The problem isnt that the model yields false for IsEnable for the button, the problem is that some style will overwrite the local value for the button.